# How can I save a file to a new location from inside Vim?

Tags: vim

I've created a Vim text file that I would like to save elsewhere (say on the desktop, or perhaps email it to myself). How could I do that? I would be glad to add any detail necessary, but I'm not quite sure what I need to add. It is purely a text file, no code in it. I'm doing this on a chromebook in developer mode, with Ubuntu installed via crouton. It is Ubuntu Version 12.04, I believe. I am rather new to Ubuntu/Linux/Bash/vim so the more detailed on how to do it, the better.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks to all answerers for their help!